# Do java use invisible pointers?

Tags: java

I recently programmed java using two int arrays. Let it be 'a' and 'b'. After assigning a=b i do some calculations on b. But without again using a=b all value of b are copied to a like a pointer to a location. This make error in my program because  i use it like normal function copying value only. Do java really use invisible pointers?

Comment: No, `a=b` just makes `a` and `b` refer to the same array. It doesn't make a copy of `b`.

Comment: You should read up on primitve types and reference types...

Comment: Think about references (in your case `a` and `b`) as just aliases for the very same object. If someone calls "mcemperor", then I respond. And if someone yells "mc", or even "emp", I respond too, because all of those aliases refer to the very same object – me. If I change my haircut, you will notice that someone you know as "mc" was changed. But you also notice that someone you know as "mcemperor" was also changed, because those are the same objects – me! **Pay attention**: an `int` is a primitive type, and primitive types don't work that way. An int array, in contrast, *is* a reference type.

Answer (score 0):

If you do 
 a=b
then is a the *same* as b - therefore each change you perform on b also is seen in a, because both variables reference the same object.